# How are Frangipani (Plumeria) cuttings taken successfully?

Tags: flowering, cuttings

I have a Frangipani which has been hacked to bits (thanks previous owner) and now the flowers are around 2 metres (7 feet) above the ground. Below that it is just a single leafless, flowerless stalk.

I would like to take cuttings and turn it into several smaller plants.

Here's where the questions start:

- What is the best size for a cutting? ie. What will be most likely to
  survive.
- Should the cuts be straight or at an angle?
- Should I treat the cuttings in some way or can I just stick them in a pot?
- How long should I wait before planting the potted cuttings?

Are there any other tips or advice that will help them thrive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a web site with some good explanation.

http://www.howtogrowplumeria.com/HT-Cuttings.htm

Comment: If you elaborate on your answer, maybe include some of the content from the link I will give you 50 bounty and mark this as correct.